# Revese string function reverses "ABC" (returns CBA) but not "012", returns "012"

Tags: c#-3.0

For a program I am writing, I need to use recursion to reverse a string
 using this function I wrote.

It inverts the strings "ABCDEFGHI" and "noob" sucessfully but fails at "01234567" it just returns "01234567" not "7654321".

Any help apreciated,

```
bool IsPalendromic(string s,out string r)
{
    var t = pal(s, s[s.Length - 1], s[0], 0);
    r = t;
    if (t == s) return true;
    return false;
}

string pal(string s, char newfirst, char newlast, int epoch)
{
    var r = s.ToArray();
    r[0]=newfirst;
    epoch++;
    r[r.Length-1] = newlast;
    if (epoch == r.Length - 1) return new string(r);
    return pal(new string(r), r[r.Length - 1], r[0], epoch);
    return "xxx";
}
```

Comment: Why have you double return statement at the end of `pal()` ?

Comment: The function is not reversing the "ABC" to "CBA" also. Some issue in the logic. please check

Comment: the xxx is because visual studio complains about not all paths returning a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String can be reversed recursively as follows

```
 char[] reverse(char[] str1, int index, int size)
       {
           char temp;
           temp = str1[index];
           str1[index] = str1[size - index];
           str1[size - index] = temp;
           if (index == size / 2)
           {
               return str1;
           }
           return reverse(str1, index + 1, size);

       }
```

call the method as

```
 string str="0123";
  char[] revchar= p.reverse(str.ToCharArray(), 0, str.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was why my implementation selectively doesn't work with number strings.

Comment: Your implementation is not working for strings like "ABCD" also. It is returning "DBCA" which is not the correct output. You are always replacing only zero'th and last index in your recursive function. And so your implementation works correctly for strings like "noob" as it replaces only "n" and "b"

Answer (score 0):

Your `pal()` only swaps the first and last letter of the `string` if the `string` has an even number of characters.

```
"ABCGEFGH" => "HBCDEFGA"
"ABCDEFGHI" => "ABCDEFGHI"
```

Consider simplifying your `pal()` to something like:

```
static string pal(string s)
{
    string reverse = "";
    for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        reverse += s[i];
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Results of `pal()` would be:

```
"ABCDEFGHI" => "IHGFEDCBA"
"ABCDEFGH" => "HGFEDCBA"
```

`IsPalendromic()` can remain the same.